# Automaticly add slug to posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks, slug

I'm using a us/news/%postname%/ structure for my permalinks. 
This works great for regular posts.

However, I have a few different custom post types, and I don't want the us/news part in their slug.

How do I have it both ways?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting `'with_front' => false` while registering the new custom post type, To remove the custom post type slug which Wordpress adds by default, pass `'slug'=>''` empty.

E.g.

```
//Example - how to pass array to rewrite
$args = array(
    // This rewrite settings will remove the slug you want also the slug - /custom_post_type/
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'','with_front'=>false),
); 
register_post_type('custom_post_type',$args);
```

Reference - [`Register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your permalink structure to `/%category%/%postname%/` and add the posts to a News category.

If you don't always want US in the URL, I suppose you could make a US category as a parent, then add the News category to it as a child. You'd have to duplicate for every country though. So you'd have to have UK -> News, then CA -> News, etc.